# Trouble Connecting to Azure Database for PostgreSQL with SSL via Looker Studio

Tags: postgresql, ssl-certificate, looker-studio, private-key

I have an Azure Database for PostgreSQL single server with SSL connection enabled. I'm trying to connect to it through Looker Studio, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

I added Google Looker Studio IP addresses inside of Azure Database Connection security.

I enter the hostname, database name, username, and password. Since SSL is enabled, I've uploaded the DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem as the Server certificate. However, I keep receiving the message: "Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request."

What could be the problem?

[Looker Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s4i8.png)

First, I attempted to upload the DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem file and then I tried the same with the old Baltimore certificate, hoping that it would work like a charm. However, it didn't. Second, I tried enabling client authentication and attempted to create client.key and client.crt files. But when it comes to the client private key, I can't upload the client.key file; it only accepts files with the .crt extension.